maximal/best element of a set of natural numbers where $x\mathbin{\mathrm{R}}y$ defined as “$x$ is a multiple of $y$”
I am doing a mock exam in social choice theory our teacher gave us and one question is:

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\,\}$ be the set of natural numbers and define $x\mathbin{\mathrm{R}}y$ as “$x$ is a multiple
of $y$”. Furthermore, let $S_1 = \{1, 2, 3, 6\} \subseteq X$ and $S_2 = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} \subseteq X$. Determine
all maximal elements and all best elements of $S_1$ and $S_2$, that is, determine the sets $M_R(S_1)$, $C_R(S_1)$, $M_R(S_2)$, and $C_R(S_2)$.

What would be the maximal/best elements in these sets? The best element being:
An element x ∈ S is a best element of S with respect to R if xRy holds
for all y ∈ S. We denote by CR(S) the set of all best elements of S with
respect to R or the choice set of S.
And maximal element being:
A maximal element of S with respect to R is any x ∈ S such that there
does not exist y ∈ S with yPx. We denote by M_R(S) the set of all
maximal elements of S with respect to R
My solutions for $S_1$ would be $C_R(S_1) = \{\}$. In this case, neither set has a best element, since there is no number (x) that is a multiple of every other numbers (y). The same would go for $C_R(S_2) = \{\}$. As for the maximal elements, it would be $M_R(S_1) = \{1,6\}$ and $M_R(S_2) = \{1,4,5,6\}$, the thought process being that e.g. 4 (x) is a multiple of 2 and 4 (y), but no other number (y) is a multiple of 4. Would this be correct?

Can you edit your question to include a definition of best element of a poset? Do you mean greatest element, a.k.a. top?

Thanks guys for the answers. I realized that I made some mistakes in my questions and edited it, adding definitions for best/maximal elements.
@aschepler I would have argued that it is, since 1 is a multiple of 1 but no other number is a multiple of 1, if we go by the definition that 1 is only a multiple of itself.

So see if you understood the definition properly, please elaborate why you think that $6$ is not a best element of $S_1$, and why it is not a best element of $S_2$.

ALso, please check again the definition your book has for "maximal element". The way you quoted it here, a reflexive relation cannot have maximal elements (and an irreflexive relation cannot have a best element)

@HagenvonEitzen I would argue that 6 is a multiple of 2 and 3, but not 1, 3, 5, so there are some y in X, where xRy does not hold. Did i understand this correctly?

@HagenvonEitzen I was just going by the definitions that are provided in the slides of my professor. I will check the book for the exact definition.

@ELBO But are there elements $y$ of $S_1$ where $6Ry$ does not hold?

@HagenvonEitzen The way you phrased your question, I would say that 6R1, 6R2 and 6R3 do hold, but I always thought that 1 is a divisor of every integer, not a multiple, so that is why I said that 6R1 does not hold.

I guess I thought about it wrong, 1 may not be a multiple of 6, but 6 is still a multiple of 1, so the best element in $S_1$ would be 6

That's a strange definition of "maximal element". Likely it should be "... such that there does not exist $y \in S$ with $y \neq x$ and $yRx$".
